# minimal polynomial of $f (a)/g (a)$, given the minimal polynomial of a

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, extension-field

I've found many exercises in which, given the minimal polynomial $p(x)\in \mathbb {F}[x] $ of $a\in \mathbb {F} $, the minimal polynomial of another expression related to that $a $ is requested.
They usually adoperate easy expressions, but I was wondering if it is always possible to find the minimal polynomial of $a'=f(a)/g(a)$ where $f(a), g(a)\in \mathbb {F}[a] $.

I think that the answer is yes, but I can't really find a solid algorithm that will always work. The general idea could be to express $a $ in terms of $a'$, this is not always that easy though, and I haven't even managed to prove that it is always possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a partial answer, the polynomials $\,p(x)\,$ and $\,a' g(x) - f(x)\,$ have the common root $\,x=a\,$, therefore the [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant#Zeros) is zero $\,\operatorname{Res}_x\big(p, a'g-f\big)\,$, which is a polynomial in $\,a'\,$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}$.

The resultant, however, is not necessarily the *minimal* polynomial, for example if $\,f \equiv g\,$ then the resultant is $\,(a'-1)^{\operatorname{deg} p}\,$ but the minimal polynomial is $\,a'-1\,$.

---

[ *EDIT* ]  For a simple example, consider the case where $a' = \dfrac{\sqrt[3]{2}+1}{\sqrt[3]{4}+1}\,$, which corresponds to $\,a=\sqrt[3]{2}\,$, $\,p(x) = x^3-2\,$, $\,f(x) = x+1\,$, $\,g(x)=x^2+1\,$.

Then [`resultant[ x^3-2, a'(x^2+1)-(x+1), x ] = 5 a'^3 + 3 a'^2 - 3 a' - 3`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=resultant%5B+x%5E3-2,+a+(x%5E2%2B1)+-+x+-+1,+x+%5D), so the polynomial $\,5x^3 +3x^2-3x-3\,$ [has $a'$ as a root](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5%20a%5E3%20%2B%203%20a%5E2%20-%203%20a%20-%203%20,%20a%20%3D%20(cbrt(2)%2B1)%20%2F%20(cbrt(4)%2B1)).

In this particular case, the resultant is in fact [the *minimal* polynomial of $\,a'\,$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimal%20polynomial%20(cbrt(2)%2B1)%20%2F%20(cbrt(4)%2B1)), though that's not necessarily true in the general case.

Comment: So, let me see if I got this straight, since the resultant is a polynomial that take the coefficients of the two polynomials in "input", and we can fix all the coefficients of f and g and let a' vary, the resultant becomes a polynomial on a', and we know that it is 0, the resultant has a' as one of its roots

Comment: @LucioTanzini Yes, precisely so.

Comment: I'd be very grateful if you showed me a simple example

Comment: @LucioTanzini I added an example at the end of the answer.

Comment: I don't know if I can use comments for thanking but this was really really helpful, you made my day

Comment: @LucioTanzini Glad it helped.